# Deleting image on laravel from storage

Tags: image, laravel

can someone please help me with this?
I have this code on controller:

```
public function deleteImage($element, $id){
    if($element != null && $id != null){
            Storage::disk('public')->deleteDirectory('/images/'.$element. '/'. $id);
    }
}
```

And I have this on the blade:

```
<script>
  $('.delete_image').click(function(){
      var img= $('#pro_img').attr("src");
      alert(img); // here is showing this myapp/public/images/questions/459/medium/11d487e5cdbde68dde65b4f396e67859
       $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/deleteImage',
        data: {'img':img},
        success: function(data){
          console.log("ajaxdata",data);
        }

      });
  });

</script>
```

And I also have the button

```
<button type="button" value="{{-- {{ $i }} --}}" class="btn btn-flat btn-default btn-sm delete_image" id="delete_image" title="@lang('buttons.remove_option')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
```

And the img:

```
<img src="{{url('/')}}/images/questions/{{ $question->id }}/medium/{{ $question->question_image }}" class="answer-image-create" id="pro_img">
```

I need to do when I click the button delete the image, can anyone help me please what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Then, you can use ```Storage::delete($filename);```

Comment: Is that really `deleteDirectory()`? For deleting file you need to call `delete()` instead.

Comment: Check this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#deleting-files

Answer (score 3):

use delete() instead of deleteDirectory() . For example,

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete($image_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Storage::disk('public')->deleteDirectory('/images/'.$element. '/'. $id);` use `Storage::disk('public')->delete('/images/'.$element. '/'. $id);`

The first one is used to delete and entire directory.
Also, I don't see you passing the second parameter ($id). In that case, the code inside the block won't run at all. If you need the ID, please send it with the request as well.